# LaTeX Commands Directories are not set

Tags: errors, installing, texstudio

I have installed LaTeX using proTeXt for learning purpose as I have to use it in near future. After I want to save a newly created file several pop-ups appear in sequence which states the some commands are not found. The first one is this

[image: First Error shown]

Searching here and there I found the commands window under `Options >> Configure TeXstudio`, where 95% of mentioned are having `<unknown>` in their directory location. Here is a snap of command window.

[image: Commands Window View].

I am totally new to this and don't know how to fix this. I have searched here and there but failed to find any proper answer. Please guide.

Comment: First of all are you 100% sure you installed a LaTeX installation? What happens if you open a command prompt and run latex? Does it respond? Did you install texstudio before or after you installed miktex/protext? It shouldn't matter, but if you had texstudio open while installing protext then it cannot find LaTeX does to how PATH changes are broadcast to the system.

Comment: Keeping in view the point in your comment "if you had texstudio open while installing protext then it cannot find LaTeX does to how PATH changes are broadcast to the system.", I uninstalled the TextStudio and reinstalled it.  
I have grabbed approximately 90% of paths now. But paths for  Biber, Texindy, Asymtote, SVN and SVNADMIN are still missing. Can you help with that too??? Thanks

Comment: Do you need them? SVN is not LaTeX related(needs an extra tool that you probably not need).

Comment: I don't know as i am just learning it for now.

Comment: Then leave it alone, it will work ok. I'm not sure if miktex installs biber by default (which might be  why it is missing). As long as your compilation does not complain about missing tolls, don't worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that i installed the TeXstudio first. This is not the actual reason but the TeXstudio was running on my system during the installation of MiKTeX 2.9. [as mentioned by @daleif in comments above].

Comment: Then in ought to be enough to just restart TeXstudio or reboot the computer